# How to make a button open a new layout xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button, layout

I'm trying to make a button for my app, which will bring the screen to another page. However, I'm not successful in doing so.

I've tried many things, without a reliefing answer.

My project doesn't accept "Intent" in my program.
My button I need to open a new layout is called "OptionButton"

Here's what I've got:

in ***MainActivity.java***
In the beginning I got this

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private Button resetButton;
    public  Button OptionButton;

/** further I got this**/

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

  /**  (I'm just mentioning this because I use savedInstanceState here too)**/

 /**MainActivity.java And my code for my button is this **/

     OptionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        OptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                myClick(v); /* my method to call new intent or activity */
            }
            public void myClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Background2.class);
                startActivity(intent);// for calling the activity
            }
        });
   }
  }
 }
```

***I added this in AndroidManifest:***

```
<activity android:name=".Background2"></activity>
```

***and this in the 2nd class (java file in src map)***

```
(package & imports, then this:
public class Background2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

_
I got 2 classes in src map:
   -Background2.java
   -MainActivity.java

Also 2 layout xml's:

- activity_main.xml
- activity main2.xml

In Activity_main, I got this for the button:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/Button1"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="35dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:text="@string/OptionButtonLabel"/>
```

Still it's not working. What am I missing?

Ty all so much!

---

I've tried changing this:

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of the listener you are calling `this` (which refers to the listener itself), while what you want to refer to is the `MainActivity`.

Simply change to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Background2.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Main Activity has to implement OnClickListner

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

From Eclipse IDE press Ctrl+Shift+O it will automatically implement and import necessary functions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers! :)

I've tried installing it on my real device.
Now, it opens, but it's the 2nd xml that opens, and when I click the button, it re-opens the same xml.

:-/

I don't get any error messages though when I changed your suggested solutions (from both of you)

Comment: To resolve that please be more elaborative. In Background2.java, check for the line setContentView(R.layout.name_of_xml_to_open); Check whether correct name is here.